# Is shadow DOM on <body> element a bad idea?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, modal-dialog, web-component, shadow-dom

Use case: A modal dialog box that, when invoked, needs to take up 100% H/W and function of all other body ancestor DOM elements. There is only one of these per page/web-app, which can hopefully be enforced when Javascript Modules arrive.

I could easily request the web-author provide something like a `<DIV></DIV>` to my web-component, a la mode de Google Maps, but is there anything intrinsically bad with attaching a Shadow DOM to document.body? It's certainly an error free option on Chrome.

A related problem is can I replace an element's shadow DOM post render? I know Shadow DOM 1.0 only permits 1 shadow DOM per element but my use case is, at run-time, I need to heuristically assemble the appropriate Template to satisfy the given temporal environment/ambiance. One way I thought of was to attach an empty Shadow DOM at load-time thereby preventing any `<SLOT>` contenders from rendering and then, when I know what UI needs to be in place, swap/clone/replace the place-holder Shadow DOM with the full-blown ridgy didge template content.

So: -
1) Is BODY as a HOST ok?
2) What is best-practice for replacing Shadow DOM?

Comment: On 2nd thoughts, with a limit of 1 Shadow DOM per element, attaching to the document.body would go against the aspirations of encapsulation and isolation by potentially forcing disparate components to compete, or at least coordinate, for a singular resource. Asking the web-author to designate the appropriate host looks "better" and more flexible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1) Is BODY as a HOST ok?

Yes

> 2) What is best-practice for replacing Shadow DOM?

Use either:

```
body.shadowRoot.innerHTML = [new template innerHTML]
```

or:

```
body.shadowRoot.replaceChild( newNodes, oldNode )
```

or:

```
body.shadowRoot.innerHTML = ''
body.shadowRoot.appendChild( newNodes )
```

With `template.content` you get directly the already parsed DocumentFragment so it could be faster in some situations, while with `template.innerHTML` you can take profit of [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), and then include the values of some variables.

Comment: Anyways you can add a full W/H modal dialog without using the body element.

Comment: Thanks for your help again. As yet I don't understand the value-added nuances of template.content over template.innerHTML but I'll read up. I guess parsed-element versus text. Good news is that appears the Shadow DOM can be closed yet still slottable. It's a shame we don't have agreement on INCLUDE but web-components are certainly becoming real!